# Why does "Edit with IDLE" show multiple options when there is only one version of python?

Tags: python, windows, python-idle

[image: My trouble]

I only have one version of Python installed on my PC. However, when I right-click a .py file then "Edit with IDLE", why does it show a nested option when there is only one? I wish to enter IDLE immediately when pressing "Edit with IDLE"

Comment: It's worth noting that Windows has a very useful "Print Screen" function, activated by the button of the same name, which takes actual screenshots.

Comment: thats an issue for me because im using 2 monitors and when i do so the image apears compressed . it is also problematic for me to find this small option across the screenshot of my two monitors to crop it out specifically. I considered using windows snipper but i cant because the submenu will disappear

Comment: Windows 10 has all kinds of built-in image processing and cropping tools as well. It's worth knowing how these work as they can save a ton of time.

Answer (score 0):

I presume your question is How?  The answer, AFAIK, is You can't.

Once upon a time, the Windows installer for Python put Edit with IDLE x.y directly on the context menu.  But with multiple installations, this cluttered the context menu.  So it was decided to put one entry in the context menu than open a submenu.  Neither solution satifies everyone.

Edit: To be more exact, you likely cannot unless you know the Windows system commands that the python.org Windows Installer uses to edit the contest menus.  It may just be adding entries to the registry.  But this is not something I would try to do.